# find \ back slash and remove it from sting php

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

I have a problem with replace \ from string

```
 <?php   $postlink = str_replace( "\" , '', $postlink); ?>
```

what's wrong with that line dreamweaver tell me that wrong line

Comment: Try echo $postlink = str_replace("\\" , "",$postlink);

Comment: use \\ instead single one, \ is a special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is a special character you need to use `\\`

```
<?php
$postlink = str_replace( "\\" , '', $postlink); 
?>
```

You can also use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) for removing slash, why are you [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)? if you have only backslashes than use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

**Example:**

```
echo stripcslashes("it\'s working day!"); //it's working day!
```